# Generate a png of a chart in Java

Tags: java, charts, java-8, visualization

I have a bunch of data generated by my java program, I want to create a png of a bar chart using these data. Does anyone know what is a good tool for this? Just simple bar chart and pie chart will work.

I cannot use JFreeChart or JavaFX since I'm running on a headless environment.

Comment: If you're running in a headless environment, then JavaFX probably isn't going to help you.

Comment: Yea, any package you would recommend?